# Vispy No module named 'vispy.visuals.text._sdf_cpu'

Tags: python, cython, vispy

I have downloaded vispy and installed all necessary dependencies (`numpy` `pyqt` and `cython`).

I am now trying to run some of the examples and when I try to run chloropleth.py for instance I get the following traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/Documents/vispy-master/examples/collections/chloropleth.py", line 11, in <module>
    from vispy.visuals.collections import PathCollection, PolygonCollection
  File "/Users/xxx/Documents/vispy-master/vispy/visuals/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .axis import AxisVisual  # noqa
  File "/Users/xxx/Documents/vispy-master/vispy/visuals/axis.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .text import TextVisual
  File "/Users/xxx/Documents/vispy-master/vispy/visuals/text/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .text import TextVisual  # noqa
  File "/Users/xxx/Documents/vispy-master/vispy/visuals/text/text.py", line 18, in <module>
    from ._sdf_cpu import _calc_distance_field
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vispy.visuals.text._sdf_cpu'
```

I am using a MacbookPro 2017 with High Sierra and `print(vispy.sys_info())` returns:

```
Platform: Darwin-17.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
Python:   3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 07:39:16)  [Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]
NumPy:    1.15.0
Backend:  PyQt5
pyqt4:    None
pyqt5:    ('PyQt5', '5.9.2', '5.9.6')
pyside:   None
pyside2:  None
pyglet:   None
glfw:     None
sdl2:     None
wx:       None
egl:      None
osmesa:   None
_test:    None
GL version:  '2.1 ATI-1.66.42'
MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
Extensions: 'GL_ARB_color_buffer_float GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float GL_ARB_depth_clamp GL_ARB_depth_texture GL_ARB_draw_buffers GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_ARB_draw_instanced GL_ARB_fragment_program GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow GL_ARB_fragment_shader GL_ARB_framebuffer_object GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB GL_ARB_half_float_pixel GL_ARB_half_float_vertex GL_ARB_imaging GL_ARB_instanced_arrays GL_ARB_multisample GL_ARB_multitexture GL_ARB_occlusion_query GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object GL_ARB_point_parameters GL_ARB_point_sprite GL_ARB_provoking_vertex GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map GL_ARB_shader_objects GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod GL_ARB_shading_language_100 GL_ARB_shadow GL_ARB_shadow_ambient GL_ARB_sync GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp GL_ARB_texture_compression GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc GL_ARB_texture_cube_map GL_ARB_texture_env_add GL_ARB_texture_env_combine GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3 GL_ARB_texture_float GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_ARB_texture_rectangle GL_ARB_texture_rg GL_ARB_transpose_matrix GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra GL_ARB_vertex_blend GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object GL_ARB_vertex_program GL_ARB_vertex_shader GL_ARB_window_pos GL_EXT_abgr GL_EXT_bgra GL_EXT_bindable_uniform GL_EXT_blend_color GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate GL_EXT_blend_func_separate GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_blend_subtract GL_EXT_clip_volume_hint GL_EXT_debug_label GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_EXT_depth_bounds_test GL_EXT_draw_buffers2 GL_EXT_draw_range_elements GL_EXT_fog_coord GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample GL_EXT_framebuffer_object GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB GL_EXT_geometry_shader4 GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters GL_EXT_gpu_shader4 GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil GL_EXT_packed_float GL_EXT_provoking_vertex GL_EXT_rescale_normal GL_EXT_secondary_color GL_EXT_separate_specular_color GL_EXT_shadow_funcs GL_EXT_stencil_two_side GL_EXT_stencil_wrap GL_EXT_texture_array GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1 GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc GL_EXT_texture_env_add GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_integer GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp GL_EXT_texture_rectangle GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent GL_EXT_texture_sRGB GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_timer_query GL_EXT_transform_feedback GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra GL_APPLE_aux_depth_stencil GL_APPLE_client_storage GL_APPLE_element_array GL_APPLE_fence GL_APPLE_float_pixels GL_APPLE_flush_buffer_range GL_APPLE_flush_render GL_APPLE_object_purgeable GL_APPLE_packed_pixels GL_APPLE_pixel_buffer GL_APPLE_rgb_422 GL_APPLE_row_bytes GL_APPLE_specular_vector GL_APPLE_texture_range GL_APPLE_transform_hint GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object GL_APPLE_vertex_array_range GL_APPLE_vertex_point_size GL_APPLE_vertex_program_evaluators GL_APPLE_ycbcr_422 GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate GL_ATI_blend_weighted_minmax GL_ATI_separate_stencil GL_ATI_texture_compression_3dc GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3 GL_ATI_texture_float GL_ATI_texture_mirror_once GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip GL_NV_blend_square GL_NV_conditional_render GL_NV_depth_clamp GL_NV_fog_distance GL_NV_light_max_exponent GL_NV_texgen_reflection GL_NV_texture_barrier GL_SGI_color_matrix GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp GL_SGIS_texture_lod '
```

Do you have any idea on how to solve this?

Have a good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to run vispy from a local directory, so it will look in the current directory first and find that one before looking at where it was installed with pip.